# Test Framework on KitKat 4.4 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'

Tags: android, android-studio, junit4

Client not ready yet..
Started running tests
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'
Empty test suite.

Answer (score 0):

Either you put your tests in "test" folder of your Android Studio project and should put them in "androidTest" folder, or the other way around.

Comment: But my test are running in other android version. i tested with android 6 and above version.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error and fixed it by Migrating the project to Androidx.